# gem install chef fails

Tags: rubygems, installation, chef-infra

When I install the chef gem there are errors as below.

```
[root@chefclient35 ~]# gem install chef -V
GET http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/chef-11.6.0.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://tokyo-m.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/chef-11.6.0.gemspec.rz
502 Bad Gateway
Error fetching remote data:             bad response Bad Gateway 502 (http://tokyo-m.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/chef-11.6.0.gemspec.rz)
Falling back to local-only install
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'chef' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: chef
```

But another machine installed on last Friday has no such kind of problem with the same environment setting. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a temporary issue of your local rubygems mirror.

It will probably be resolve soon by the rubygems.org maintainer. If that is not the case, you could try to contact them.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try to contact the maintainer or to find a different way of handling chef installation.